Is there a faster way to show that $f(x) = 1 - x^3 + x^5 \neq 0$ for $x \in [0,1]$?
Naturally, I would find critical points of this function in $[0,1]$ and show that the minimum value of $f(x)$ in this interval is greater than $0$ and conclude that $f(x) \neq 0$. However, I strongly feel there is a more clever way. I've tried considering $f(x) = (1-x^3) + x^5$ and $f(x) = 1 + (x^5 -x^3)$, but none seem to lead to anything. I'd love to know if better approaches are available.
Thank you!

1).by graphing f(x) 2) by find roots of f(x)

Just because I’ve asked lots of this kind of questions, the word “faster” can differ by person. Except the situation that someone has very brilliant method, this kind of questions seems a bit vague to me, with my experiences.

Yes. $x=0$ and $x=1$ aren't roots. At a root, $x^3-x^5=1$. But when $x\in(0,1)$, $0<x^5<x^3<1$ so this is impossible.

Thank you very much!

You might note that for $0 < x < 1$, $x^5 > 0$ and $1 - x^3 > 0$ so
$1 - x^3 + x^5 = (1 - x^3) + x^5 > 0$...

Thank you very much! I was too focused on the closed interval as a whole without thinking of checking $f(1)$ and $f(0)$ separately. I wish I could accept more than one answer, but your approach is also very neat! Thank you again!

For $x\in [0,1]$ we have $1-x^3\geq 0$ and therefore $1-x^3+x^5\geq x^5$. $x^5$ is nonnegative for $x\in [0,1]$ and the only root of $x^5$ is not a root of $1-x^3+x^5$.

If $f(x)=0$ when $x\in (0,1],$ then $1+x^5 = x^3,\implies 2\leq\frac{1}{x^{5/2}} + x^{5/2} = \sqrt{x},\Rightarrow\Leftarrow.$

It should be $2 \le \cdots$

@jjagmath fixed, thanks.

For $0\le x<4$,
$$1-x^3+x^5 = x(x^2-\tfrac12)^2+1-\tfrac x4\ge 1-\frac x4>0$$

For $0<x\le 1$ we have $$1\ge x^3>x^3-x^5$$
